# property return text from each row datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, textbox

I need a property that returns text for each row from my `datagridview`. I don't know if the way how I am doing may work .It says on get that i is not in the current context . My code:

```
  TextBox[] text1=new TextBox[100];

  public string [] RowText
    {
        get
        {
                return text1[i].Text; 
        }
        set
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridview1.Rows)
            {
                for ( i = 0; i < datagridview1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    text1[i].Text= row.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Apart of what gzaxx mentioned regarding the getter, pay attention to the setter: you are using the row index `i` for accessing the cells ? That's wrong also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if `i` is not a global variable then it should be declared inside `get` clause. Then `text1[i].Text` return single string but your Property returns an array, so change it to:

```
get
{
        return new string[] { text1[i].Text };
}
```

also your set does not make much sense. If you explain better what you want to achieve maybe I may help you out.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have multiple controls dynamically created on winform. I need to get the text of which row and to store this in an XML doc. For each control I will have other values on my grid,so in XML,each control has to have its values. But this works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need the setter - put the code in the getter or in the object's constructor. And you are returning an array of TextBox objects but your property signature states you are returning an array of strings.

If you want to return a string array, then perhaps:

```
  public string [] RowText
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> text = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridview1.Rows)
            {
                text.Add(row.Cells[i].Value.ToString());
            }
            return text.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Actually, looking closer at your code, it may fail because of the `for` loop. Your code assumes that the row contains the same number of cells as there are rows. This may be true for your scenario, but unlikely.